# Search help is not giving exact results in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have written code for search fields in ui5 controllers files, But the search field is not giving expected output when I pasted particular column value in input search field. Instead if I type the value in search field it is giving exact output.
I have used livechange event. I also tried with search event but unable to get the output.
I am using odata services.

Below is the controller file code:

```
    onSearch: function(oEvt) {

        // add filter for search
        var aFilters = [];
        var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
        if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
            var filter = new Filter("UNIQUE_ID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sQuery);
            aFilters.push(filter);
        }

        // update list binding
        var list = this.byId("orderTable");
        var binding = list.getBinding("items");
        binding.filter(aFilters);

    }
```

View code:
Label class="sapUiMediumMarginTop" text="Unique Id"

SearchField width="150px" class="sapUiSmallMargin" liveChange="onSearch"

Please suggest me if I am missing anything.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does your data look like?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, It is not giving the correct output. When I am copying one value ex:10047962, It is displaying the values for 10047961 in the report. Where as if I type 10047962 in search field everything is working fine. I am actually confused with this behavior. Usually most people will do testing by copying values right instead of typing the whole value. In that case my code is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you out? I tested your code with some random data and it worked for me.

```
    onSearch: function(oEvent) {
        var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");

        var oFilter1 = new Filter("Name", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
        var oFilter2 = new Filter("Age", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
        var arrFilter = new Filter([oFilter1, oFilter2], false);

        // filter binding
        var oList = this.byId("idList");
        var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
        oBinding.filter(arrFilter);
    },
```

Comment: Did u directly enter the data or copied the data in search field? Because if I copy and paste some values in search field, it is not working for me in my code.

Comment: I can see blank values Matthijs after placing the provided code and giving search field input..

Comment: I was on a holiday. Did you fix this issue by now?